# What is the limit on dropped candies?

Tags: candy-box-2

I'm playing Candy Box 2 and on the Candy Box home screen you can drop 10 candies, I'm already in the room with huge candies and all the dude is doing is eating them, is there something after those candies that he is eating or does he just eat them no matter how many you drop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've hit the end. It's just a loop of candy eating after that. You can keep throwing as many as you want though!

(The loop starts at 1770.)